# I am creating a python program that counts the number of characters input by user in a file that is not case-sensitive

Tags: python, programming-languages

I am having problem with my code and a TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str. Any help or suggestion?

my code is:

```
f= open("studentname.txt", 'r')
finChar = raw_input("please enter a character to count ")
a=finChar.lower()
b=finChar.upper()
c=a+b
str = ''
for line in f.readlines():
     str = str + line
count = 0
for i in str:
    if str[i]== c :
        count = count + 1
f.close()
print "the total character in the file is ", count
```

Comment: You don't want to do `c = a+b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for i in str` iterates over the characters in a string, not their indices. Therefore you can write

```
for i in str:
    if i in c:
```

Answer (score 2):

`for i in str` gives you the characters in `str`, not the indices to index into `str` by.

Try `if i == c` instead of `if str[i] == c`.

Comment: i tried that and it got ride of the error message but im back to the this program doesn't do what i want it to do. i still cant have it count the character in my file w/o case-sensitivity. thanks for the help thought :)